# Unable to run Reco4j basic example

Tags: neo4j, nosql, graph-databases

Hello I am new to Neo4j and Reco4j, I would like to run the first example:

http://www.reco4j.org/get-started.jsp

but when  I paste the code:

```
Properties properties = loadProperties();
Neo4jGraph graphDB = new Neo4jGraph();
graphDB.setProperties(properties);
graphDB.initDatabase();
```

I get a sintax error, since Neo4jGraph() needs a INeo4JGraphConfig object as a parameter, I have searched for other examples but I haven't found anything. Where could I find a complete basic example of Neo4j and Reco4j?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

could copy and paste here the error? 
What version are you using? 
Moreover could I suggest you to have a look to the example in the test source code available here: 
https://github.com/reco4j/reco4j-neo4j/tree/master/src/test/java

Regards,
Alessandro

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help. I am testing the example in the "get started" section of RECO4J:http://www.reco4j.org/get-started.jsp

Answer (score 0):

there is an error in the getting started page since we change a little bit the signature of the constructor.
You can proceed in this way:

```
Properties properties = loadProperties();
Neo4JPropertiesHandle.getInstance().setProperties(properties);
Neo4jGraph graphDB = new Neo4jGraph(Neo4JPropertiesHandle.getInstance());
graphDB.initDatabase();
```

Moreover, please have a look at our examples here:

https://github.com/reco4j/reco4j-neo4j/tree/master/src/test/java

You'll find more interesting example.
If you want you can use also our google group:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/reco4j

Or contact us, details are available here: http://www.reco4j.org/contacts.jsp

Cheers,
Alessandro